# Is there any difference between the following two?

Tags: c++

I define a global non-member method for + overloading

Like

```
ClassA operator+(const ClassA& a, const ClassB& b);
{
   blah blah ;
}
```

In the communicative one, I can use

1)

```
ClassA operator+(const ClassB& b, const ClassA& a)
{
      return operator+(a,b);
}
```

2)

```
ClassA operator+(const ClassB& b, const ClassA& a)
{
       return a + b;
}
```

Any difference between 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes, the second one is more readable.

Comment: Overloading the + operator is done exactly so you can use the second case. Otherwise you would just use functions. It doesn't make a difference but it's much more clean and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the obvious difference pointed out first by @barakmanos in the comments ("the second one is more readable"), there is another technical difference.

Assume for a second, the following definitions:

```
struct B;

struct A
{
    void operator+(B const&) const { ::std::cout << "member\n"; }
    friend void operator+(A const&, B const&) { ::std::cout << "friend\n"; }
};

struct B { };
```

Now, consider the following three statements:

```
    operator+(A(), B());
    A().operator+(B());
    A() + B();
```

The first one obviously calls the friend (free) function, the second one calls the member. However, the third one would call either if the other was not defined. In this special case, it cannot find a better match and would thus be ill formed. There are a few ways to modify this behaviour, e.g. if the member function was different in `const`-requirements, the expression could be correct and just lead to a larger overload set.

This demonstrates the difference in your two expressions: `operator+(a,b)` *only* considers free functions and not member functions overloading the binary plus operator.

In fact, the C++ standard has an example for another difference:

`A() + B()` *only* does argument dependent lookup, while `operator+(A(), B())` does a normal function lookup. This means that the following is an error (taken from C++11 §13.3.1.2.10):

```
struct A { };
void operator + (A, A);
struct B {
    void operator + (B);
    void f ();
};
A a;
void B::f() {
    operator+ (a,a); // error: global operator hidden by member
    a + a; // OK: calls global operator+
}
```